# How to import JSON file to mongodb from Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, parsing, import

```
{
    "colorsArray" : [ {
        "colorName" : "red",
        "hexValue" : "#f00"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "green",
        "hexValue" : "#0f0"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "blue",
        "hexValue" : "#00f"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "cyan",
        "hexValue" : "#0ff"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "magenta",
        "hexValue" : "#f0f"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "yellow",
        "hexValue" : "#ff0"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "black",
        "hexValue" : "#000"
    } ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an sample example from my code.You can use it as your need.

```
DBObject obj = (DBObject) com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(sample_json);
put all obj into a list,

List<DBObject> listObject = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(obj);
//save them into database:
new MongoClient().getDB("dbname").getCollection("collection").insert(list);
```

**UPDATE ANSEWR :**

**TOTAL CODE :**

```
package com.demo.mongo;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

/**
 * Java MongoDB : Convert JSON data to DBObject and insert it to dab
 *
 */

public class JsonApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("ipaddress", 27017);
            DB db = mongo.getDB("dbname");
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("dummyColl");

            // convert JSON to DBObject directly

            DBObject obj = (DBObject) JSON.parse("sample_json");

            collection.insert(dbObject);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide me the whole code as m getting error in line:List<DBObject> listObject = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Probably a reference...!

Comment: FYI DBObject is deprecated and the relevent parse method can be accessed with BasicDBObject.parse().

Comment: Upvoted, but JSON object seems to be long gone. Used BasicDBObject.parse() method as @Shn_Android_Dev suggested, works

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "how to insert a document into mongodb". Something like this should work.

```
db.colors.insertMany(
   [ {
        "colorName" : "red",
        "hexValue" : "#f00"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "green",
        "hexValue" : "#0f0"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "blue",
        "hexValue" : "#00f"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "cyan",
        "hexValue" : "#0ff"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "magenta",
        "hexValue" : "#f0f"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "yellow",
        "hexValue" : "#ff0"
    }, {
        "colorName" : "black",
        "hexValue" : "#000"
    } ]
)
```

Now you need to find out how you want to do this. there are multiple ways to do this in java.

If you are new to using document based databases and want to keep things easy I would look into using [Spring data](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/). However you could just the mongodb java driver. There are numerous tutorials on how to do it like [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/).

Answer (score -1):

```
mongoimport --host localhost --port 37017 --username user --password pass --collection collectionName --db databaseName --file fileName
```

Comment: Thanks sam! But I want to do it from java not directly.